# Proof If $AB-I$ Invertible then $BA-I$ invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have these problems :

- Proof If $AB-I$ invertible then $BA-I$ invertible.
- Proof If $I-AB$ invertible then $I-BA$ invertible.

I think I solve it correctly, But I'm not so sure, I'll be glad to receive feedback.

- If $AB-I$ invertible then :  $$\det|AB-I| \neq 0 \implies \\ \det|A-I||B| \neq 0 \implies \\ \det|B||A-I| \neq 0 
  \implies\\ \det|BA-I| \neq 0$$

Therefore $BA-I$ invertible.

- If $I-AB$ invertible then :

$$\det|I-AB| \neq 0 \implies \\
\det|I-B||A| \neq 0 \implies \\
\det|I-BA| \neq 0$$

Therefore $I-BA$ invertible.

Comment: No, this is not correct. $I-AB$ has nothing to do with $\left(I-B\right) A$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Both of them are not correct?

Comment: The two problems are equivalent, aren't they? Isn't $I-AB = -(AB-I)$, and $I-BA = -(BA-I)$? (And of course $X$ is invertible iff $-X$ is invertible.)

Comment: @JaVaPG: Yes, both of them.

Comment: See also [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675034/finding-inverse-in-non-commutative-ring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way to prove this statement:

1. You want to prove that $BA-I$ is invertible if $AB-I$ is invertible. This is equivalent to proving that $AB-I$ is *not* invertible if $BA-I$ is not invertible.
2. Can you relate non-invertibility to some condition on the eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$? **Hint**: $0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB-I$ if and only if $1$ is an eigenvalue for $AB$.
3. Finally, what is the relation between the eigenvalues of $AB$ and those of $BA$?

If you want more hints, just ask, but please try to solve it by yourself first.

Comment: @M Turgeon I didn't study eigenvalues so much but I think I got the answers, If $0$ is an eigenvalue then we can conclude that the matrix is not invertible,  AB and BA has the same eigenvalues, Therefore if AB invertible then BA invertible.

Comment: @JaVaPG You're close, but that's not quite the answer. Recall that you are trying to prove $BA-I$ is invertible, not $BA$.

Comment: @M Turgeon Therefore if $1$ is an eigenvalue for $AB$ or $BA$ then both $AB-I$, $BA-I$ are not invertible, and since we know that $AB-I$ is invertible $0$ isn't an eigenvalue which implies that $0$ isn't an eigenvalue for $BA-I$ therefore 1 is not an eigenvalue for $BA$ so $BA$ invertible.

Comment: @JaVaPG Correct.

Comment: @M Turgeon Thank you for your help, question 2 is the same thing just instand of eigenvalue of 1, its eigenvalue of -1 for $AB/BA$, right?

Comment: good answer I really like it +1 for you

Comment: @JaVaPG Yes, exactly. But as MPW (and Kaladin) mentioned, the two problems are basically equivalent (since $AB-I=-(I-BA)$).

Answer (score 25):

There's a slick way to *discover* the inverse by first solving the problem for (formal) power series.

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm (1-ab)^{-1} &=&\rm 1+ ab + a\color{#c00}{ba}b + a\color{#0a0}{baba}b +\,\cdots\\
&=&\rm 1+ a (1\, +\, \color{#c00}{ba}\ \ +\ \ \color{#0a0}{baba}\,\ +\,\cdots)b\\
&=&\rm 1+ a (1\,-\,ba)^{-1}b\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

Simple algebra *proves* that this formula is universally correct (as in Kaladin's answer).

At first glance, it seems *highly* remarkable that such a method should work. Halmos posed the challenge of explaining why this works in one of his popular expositions in *Math. Intelligencer*. Some explanations are known - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/675128/242) for more (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/356486/242)).

Comment: Great reference. Thanks. (+1)

Comment: That's great idea!

Answer (score 8):

If $AB-I$ is invertible with inverse $C$ then look at $-I+BCA$ as inverse of $BA-I$.
\begin{align}
(BA-I)(-I+BCA) &=-BA+BABCA+I-BCA\\
&= -BA+B(AB-I)CA+I\\
&=-BA+BA+I=I
\end{align}
and for the other side
\begin{align}
(-I+BCA)(BA-I)&=-BA+I+BCABA-BCA\\
&=-BA+BC(AB-I)A+I\\
&= -BA+BA+I=I
\end{align}
For the second part you can do something similar. Assume $I-AB$ has inverse $D$, which is $-C$, then $I-BA$ has inverse $I+BDA=-(-I+BCA)$.

Comment: See my answer for a remarkable way to *discover* the above inverse formula.

Answer (score 1):

Your result will be true if $A$ or $B$  is supposed to be invertible.

Since we have $\det(ABA-A)=\det(A(BA-I))$:

$$ \det((AB-I)A)=\det (A(BA-I))\implies
 \det A\cdot\det (AB-I)=\det A \cdot\det(BA-I).$$

result follows if $\det A\neq0$.

Moreover $$\begin{align}\det(BA-I)\cdot\det B &= \det((BA-I)B)\\ &=\det(BAB-B)\\&=\det(B(AB-I))\\&=\det B\cdot \det(AB-I).\end{align}$$

Result follows if $\det B \neq 0$.

Comment: I don't think this is a counter-example. I may have made a computation mistake, but I have
$$AB-I = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-2&-2\end{pmatrix}$$
and also
$$BA-I = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},$$
and neither are invertible. Moreover, you give a proof for when $A$ is invertible, which is the case in your "counter-example".