# Matrix Identity $(I-G_1G_2)^{-1}G_1=G_1(I-G_2G_1)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory

I am reading a book on control theory for multiple input multiple output (MIMO) systems. The author claims that for the identity matrix $I$ and the complex transfer function matrices $G_1$ and $G_2$ (let us assume they are square matrices) the following identity holds:
$$(I-G_1G_2)^{-1}G_1=G_1(I-G_2G_1)^{-1}.$$

Is this statement true? And how can I derive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is true. It can be derived from
$$
G_1(I-G_2G_1) = G_1-G_1G_2G_1 = (I-G_1G_2)G_1
$$
Multiply $(I-G_1G_2)^{-1}$ from the left and $(I-G_2G_1)^{-1}$ from the right and you will get the original identity.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the quick and easy answer. Will accept the answer to be correct in 4 minutes :D.

Comment: There is a caveat: you don't know if  $I-G_1G_2$ and $I-G_2G_1$ are simultaneously invertible ! See the answer of Andreas Caranti and (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1398275).

Comment: @JeanMarie I would say, this is subject to interpretation. You could argue that the usage of $(I-G_1G_2)^{-1}$ and $(I-G_2G_1)^{-1}$ in the question implies their existence.

Comment: I agree that, in the way MrYouMath has asked his question, there is this implied assumption...

Answer (score 3):

You need, say, $I - G_{2} G_{1}$ to be invertible, and then you can ***prove that $I - G_{1} G_{2}$ is invertible***, and that the identity holds.

In fact, under these hypotheses, you have
$$\tag{eq}
(I - G_{1} G_{2}) G_{1} (I - G_{2} G_{1})^{-1}
=
(G_{1} - G_{1} G_{2} G_{1}) (I - G_{2} G_{1})^{-1}
=
G_{1} (I - G_{2} G_{1}) (I - G_{2} G_{1})^{-1}
=
G_{1}.
$$
In particular 
$$
G_{1} G_{2} = (I - G_{1} G_{2}) X
$$
for some $X$, so that
$$
I = G_{1}G_{2} + (I - G_{1} G_{2}) =
(I - G_{1} G_{2}) X + (I - G_{1} G_{2})
=
(I - G_{1} G_{2}) (X + I),
$$
and $I - G_{1} G_{2}$ is invertible. Now multiply by $(I - G_{1} G_{2})^{-1}$ on the left in (eq).