# proof that $(I+AB)^{-1}A = A(I+BA)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Given $A, I+AB\:$ invertible matrices, prove that $I+BA$ is invertible and that
$$(I+AB)^{-1}A = A(I+BA)^{-1}.$$

How should I approach this? The question seems similar to [Proof if $I+AB$ invertible then $I+BA$ invertible and $(I+BA)^{-1}=I-B(I+AB)^{-1}A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398275/proof-if-iab-invertible-then-iba-invertible-and-iba-1-i-biab-1) but I can't make the connection

Comment: @enzotib here it is not given that  A,I+AB invertible matrices, so the solution's may differ

Answer (score 6):

Hint : $$A^{-1}(I+AB)A = I + BA$$

Comment: Why is this true?

Comment: Distributive property...

Comment: @avivgood2 Since $$\left(A^{-1}(I+AB)\right)A = (A^{-1} + B)A=I+BA$$

Answer (score 3):

Start with
$$
       A(I+BA)=(I+AB)A
$$
If $A$, $I+AB$ are invertible, then
$$
               (I+BA)=A^{-1}(I+AB)A,
$$
which makes $I+BA$ invertible, with
$$
               (I+BA)^{-1}=A^{-1}(I+AB)^{-1}A
$$
Multiplying on the left by $A$ gives the desired result:
$$
                          A(I+BA)^{-1}=(I+AB)^{-1}A.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Well... if you follow the answer to that question you get that $I+BA$ is invertible. Furthermore,

\begin{align}
A(I+BA)^{-1}&=A-AB(I+AB)^{-1}A=(I-AB(I+AB)^{-1})A\\
&=(I-(I+AB)(I+AB)^{-1}+(I+AB)^{-1})A\\
&= (I-I+(I+AB)^{-1})A\\
&=(I+AB)^{-1}A,
\end{align}
and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

If you accept that $I+AB$ invertible implies $I+BA$ invertible and $(I+BA)^{-1}
=I-B(I+AB)^{-1}A$ then
\begin{align}
A(I+BA)^{-1}&=A-AB(I+AB)^{-1}A=A+(I-(I+AB))(I+AB)^{-1}A\\
&=A+(I+AB)^{-1}A-A=(I+AB)^{-1}A.
\end{align}