# Show I - AB is invertible related

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n$ x $n$ matrices over reals. Show that $I - BA$ is invertible if $I - AB$ is invertible. Deduce that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues.

I know how to prove that $AB$ and $BA$ have same eigen values, when either $A$ or $B$ is non-singular.

But here, that condition is not mentioned.

Please help me.

Comment: Use the determinant

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
B^{-1}(I-BA)B=I-AB.
$$
Hence $\det(I-BA)=\det(I-AB)$, so that $I-BA$ is invertible if and only if $I-AB$ is invertible. Actually, the question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078781/proof-if-ab-i-invertible-then-ba-i-invertible?rq=1) already. The second part is a duplicate as well, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821934/eigenvalues-of-ab-and-ba-matrices), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124888/are-the-eigenvalues-of-ab-equal-to-the-eigenvalues-of-ba-citation-needed).