# Let $A$, $B$ be square matrices of order $2$ such that $|I_2 + AB| = 0$. Prove that $|I_2 + BA| = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

In this question, I denote
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix},$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix}.$$
So, from $|I_2 + AB| = 0$, I'll have:
$$(ae+fc+1)(gb+hd+1) = (ga+hc)(eb+fd).$$

If $|I_2 + BA| = 0$ (which we have to prove here), then
$$(ae+bg+1)(cf+hd+1) = (af+bh)(ce+dg).$$
From both equations, I can see that what we're going to prove here is $cf=bg$, more precisely, $g=f$ and $b=c$.

Is my thinking path right or wrong?
I still have not figured out the solution yet, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you studied eigenvalues? If you do, try to think of what $\det(I_2+AB)=0$ means in terms of eigenvalues.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31595/how-would-you-solve-this-tantalizing-halmos-problem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078781/proof-if-ab-i-invertible-then-ba-i-invertible

Comment: Regarding your approach so far, there is no reason to believe that we have $g = f$ or $b = c$. As an example, if we take
$$
A = B = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0},
$$
then it is true that $|I + AB| = 0$, but it is not true that $g = f$ or $b = c$.

Comment: Proof on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity

Comment: Order 2 like $A^{2} = I$?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
|I_2 + AB| = a e (d h + 1) - b c f g + d h + 1
$$
which is clearly invariant under swapping
$a\leftrightarrow e$,
$b\leftrightarrow f$,
$c\leftrightarrow g$,
$d\leftrightarrow h$.
Hence
$$
|I_2 + AB| = |I_2 + BA|
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|I + AB| = 0$ if and only if $I + AB$ is non-invertible, which is true if and only if the equation $(I + AB) x = 0$ has a non-zero solution $x$.

Suppose that $x \neq 0$ is such that $(I + AB)x = 0$. We see that
$$
Ix + ABx = 0 \implies ABx = -x.
$$
Note that because $A(Bx) = -x \neq 0$, it must be the case that $Bx \neq 0$.
Using our observations so far, note that
$$
BA(Bx) = B(AB)x = B(-x) = -Bx.
$$
In other words, $Bx \neq 0$, and we have
$$
BA(Bx) = -Bx \implies IBx + BABx = 0 \implies (I + BA)Bx = 0.
$$
So, the equation $I + BA y = 0$ has a non-zero solution. It follows that $|I + BA| \neq 0$, which was what we wanted.

Comment: I think maybe you want a couple of edits in your last two sentences?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a corollary (taking $n = m = 2$) of the result below:

For $A \in F^{m \times n}, B \in F^{n \times m}$, it follows that
\begin{equation}
\det(I_{(m)} + AB) = \det(I_{(n)} + BA). \tag{$*$}
\end{equation}

To prove identity $(*)$, consider the block matrix:
\begin{align}
\Delta = \begin{pmatrix} I_{(m)} & A \\
-B & I_{(n)} 
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
and verify decompositions below:
\begin{align*}
& \begin{pmatrix}
I_{(m)} & A \\
-B & I_{(n)} 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} I_{(m)} & 0 \\
B & I_{(n)} 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{(m)} + AB & A \\
0 & I_{(n)} 
\end{pmatrix}, \tag{1} \\
& \begin{pmatrix}
I_{(m)} & A \\
-B & I_{(n)} 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} I_{(m)} & -A \\
0 & I_{(n)} 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{(m)} & 0 \\
-B & I_{(n)} + BA 
\end{pmatrix} \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Taking determinants on both sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ then yields
$$\det(\Delta) = \det(I_{(m)} + AB) = \det(I_{(n)} + BA).$$